# button type submit refreshes page instead of triggering ajax network request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have the following form:

```
 <div class="contact-form-container" action="https://www.serverlessform.com/f/8b24308d" method="POST">
    <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
      <label>
        <p class="contact-label">Your email:</p>
        <input placeholder="example@host.com" type="email" id="email" name="email">
      </label>
      <label>
        <p class="contact-label">Text:</p>
        <textarea placeholder="Your message here..." id="text" name="text"></textarea>
      </label>
      <button id="contact-submit" type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

and the following script for the submit button:

```
  $('#contact-submit').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.serverlessform.com/f/8b24308d',
      method: 'POST',
      success: function (response) {
        // { submission: { ...fields...}, auto_response: { ...body...}
        console.log(response);
      },
    });
  });
```

Now when I input data into my form and click the button, my page refreshes and the network request gets cancelled. I can see the actual request logged in the network tab in chrome, but instead of sending it, the page refreshes and the request gets cancelled.

I built the form and the ajax call from the following example on serverless forms:

```
<form action="https://www.serverlessform.com/f/8b24308d" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
  <label>Email
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<button id="btn-demo" type="submit">AJAX Button</button>
<script>
$('#btn-demo').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.serverlessform.com/f/8b24308d',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
      // { submission: { ...fields...}, auto_response: { ...body...}
      console.dir(response);
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

So the expected behavior is for the form to submit a POST request to the serverlessform URL. Instead, the page refreshes and canceless the Network request.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: aint it because its a submit button inside a form`? then it refresh because of that?

Comment: Change it to `type="button"` or use `preventDefault()` on the event.

Comment: either change to `type="button"` or use `event.preventDefault();`. or move the button outside of form.